# Getting warning : implode(): after receiving a var value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having the following errors:

> Warning : array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in...
>
> Warning : implode(): Invalid arguments passed in wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 1918

On my php I am receiving a var from another page and I do:

```
$myId = $_POST['varPostId'];
$parts = explode(',', $myId);
```

And then I need to read that value

```
query_posts(array(
    'post__in' => $myId
));
```

But I get the above errors.

if I do:

```
    'post__in' => $parts
));
```

I get a blank page.

I tried using `implode`

```
$myId = $_POST['varPostId'];
$parts = implode(',', $myId);
```

And getting the value directly in the query

```
query_posts(array(
    'post__in' => $_POST['varPostId']
));
```

`$_POST['varPostId']` is a single value like `405`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171688/discussion-on-question-by-rob-m-getting-warning-implode-after-receiving-a-v).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the value you're getting from the `POST` request is containing just a single post ID which should be an int but is possibly a string. You'll need to do some type and error checking. Something like the following should hopefully work. I see [`query_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) and `post__in`, I'm assuming WordPress is at play here?

```php
// Put your ID into a variable and sanitize it
$myId = sanitize_key( $_POST['varPostId'] );

// Force it to an int (in case it's not from sanitize_key)
$myId = (int) $myId;

// Don't explode because it's not appropriate here
// $parts = explode( ',', $myId );

// Add the post id to the arguments as an array
query_posts(
  array(
    'post__in' => array( $myId )
  )
);
```

To follow up on why `explode` isn't appropriate here, it's used to convert a string, usually something like this:

> oh, hello, world

Into an array with multiple items like the following:

```
$asdf = array(
  0 => 'oh',
  1 => 'hello',
  2 => 'world'
);
```

But you it seems that you don't have a comma separated string of post ids, you just have the one so it's best not used here.

As already stated in the comments, [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) takes a string and splits it into an array of items. [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) does the opposite. It takes an array and condenses it down into a string.

So you could have something such as:

```php
$myArray = array(
  0 => 'hello',
  1 => 'world'
);

// Convert to a string
$myString = implode( ', ', $myArray );

echo $myString; // prints: hello, world

// Convert back to an array
$myString = explode( ', ', $myArray );

var_dump( $myString ); // prints the array above
```

Comment: yeah thanks but I did the `var_dump($_POST['varPostId']);` .. and it is an array what I get `string(5) "Array"`  I really did try anything, all worked when I did `'p' => $_POST['varPostId'],` instead of `'post__in' => $_POST['varPostId']`

Comment: @actually mine isn't working... but yours, the first bit you mentioned, gives a blank page..

Comment: I had to use 'p' => array( $myId ),