# How to get the correct values as array from post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a search, with a select range, when I submit, on the other page I do:

```
<?php 
    $myId = $_POST['myDates'];
    echo $myId;
?>
```

That gives me:

```
1664,1899
```

But If I do:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key'     => 'usp-custom-14',
    'meta_value'   => array( $myId ),
    'type'    => 'numeric',
    'meta_compare' => 'BETWEEN'
)
```

I won't get the correct results while if I manually insert the numbers:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key'     => 'usp-custom-14',
    'meta_value'   => array( 1664,1899 ),
    'type'    => 'numeric',
    'meta_compare' => 'BETWEEN'
)
```

Works fine. Looks like I am doing something wrong with the way I am retrieving the values as an array.

If I do `var_dummp($myid);` I get `string(9) "1664,1899"`

Comment: You did correct way - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Also, you can try with date query - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: @Jaydp yes I know but I was already getting an array

Comment: @Jaydp it isn't a date but a range of num values..

Comment: Somebody downvoted my answer, so I thought I was not right:(

Comment: Why did i get a down vote?

Comment: @Sakezzz i didn't give any down vote. DId you give it my question?

Comment: @rob.m no, I didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your $myId is already an array, so when you

```
'meta_value'   => array( $myId )
```

you basically wrap array into an array

```
'meta_value'   => array( array (1664,1899) )
```

hence no output

Try

```
'meta_value'   => $myId
```

Comment: Bingo! Yes it was already an array. Thanks a lot, will accept as soon as it let me.

Comment: i believe Viarys is right. please update your question @rob.m to have same data returned for future viewers thx.

Comment: No problems. I am curious who gave me a down vote right away. I feel like there are just some real haters on the forum lol

Comment: @CodeofGod it's Biarys :)

Comment: @Biarys i had to delete a comment as I was asking who gave you a down vote and why? But looks like they've removed it.. Thanks once again

Comment: @Biarys Oh! I now have a down vote on my question too. And yout oo again. Why?!

Comment: No idea. This happened to my other answers as well lol. have my upvote @rob.m

Answer (score 0):

Try `(array) $myId` or just `$myId`. Sorry, I thought $myId was array

Comment: im not sure why you think you can type cast a string into an array, but you can't.

Answer (score -1):

you need to explode your string.

```
<?php 
    $myId = explode(",",$_POST['myDates']);
    echo $myId;
?>
```

also please fix your variable names, they are very misleading.

Comment: I already tried it and gives me `array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "1664" [1]=> string(4) "1899" }` but an error too `Warning
: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in`

Comment: @rob.m thats because you didnt give us the proper data returned "1664,1899" and apparently by the looks of it your data is actually an array and not a string as suggested in your post.

Comment: I did tho, I placed both the `echo` and the `var_dump` values

Comment: vardump would have given you an array output not a string "1664,1899" @Briarys answer was a good shot in the dark, you didn't give us proper information.

Comment: I really did give you what I had. I have not idea why it was giving a string, I had a similar problem here and read the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50503215/1018804

Comment: what  want to know is why this answer has a down vote.